# how to delete the back slash from any path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

1.I have a path \\\\arvind\chaudhary\newfolder\ want to remove two backword 
  slash from this path and want as below

2.I want the path \\arvind\chaudhary\newfolder\

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Not very much, I'd venture. :-)

Comment: Why your path has 4 leading blackslashes at all?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this,

```
string a = @"\\\\arvind\chaudhary\newfolder\";
a = a.Replace(@"\\\\", @"\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var str  = @"\\\\arvind\chaudhary\newfolder\";
str = str.Replace(@"\\\\", @"\\");
```

returns

> \\arvind\chaudhary\newfolder\

Comment: Yeah What's new in this from my answer buddy other than variable name?

Comment: Haha Lolz let's upvote each others answers

Comment: @MihirDave The difference is, that your solution also changes paths with \\arvind\ to \arvind\ because you forgot the @ within replace.